# Jsoup parsing android URL connecting issue

Tags: android, html, parsing, xhtml, jsoup

I have previously asked another question which can be seen at : [Jsoup parsing HTML issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402652/jsoup-parsing-html-issue) . I was trying to parse a data value from a website to my android app. I now realize that although in my app I give the url of the web page with the data I need, when I connect to the url from my app it always connects to the login page of the website instead and therefore doesn't find the data to parse. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this?

Comment: Why don't you open that `webPage` in `webView` ?

Comment: I would but the user will not be logging in personally to the site and I don't want them to see any of that in the app. Basically they are connecting to a site where I input a value and using Jsoup I parse that value from my android app and use it in my app. All the user sees is the effects of what I do with that value once it's retrieved.

Comment: You can do that if you're getting response in your website.

Comment: Can you explain more in depth what you mean please?

Comment: I'm asking you, you're getting `JSON` data via API or it gets display on `webPage`?

Comment: You probably need to login to the website, using a cookie. I believe there are some questions about this on SO already.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Yes, I am getting JSON data via Jsoup API.

Answer (score 0):

@JonasCz You are correct sir! I just had to login to my site using a cookie which I then passed on to my app when I requested a connection to the web page that I was parsing to get my data.